# Keeping DNN page unauthenticated for authenticated users, for output cache purposes

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, caching, dotnetnuke

Is there a way to keep a DNN(8.5) page unauthenticated for authenticated users, for output cache purposes?

Some of our archive pages are heavy, and we rely on output caching to make them load fast (<3s). However, when an authenticated user navigates to those pages, they get the uncached version which may take 15-30 seconds to load.

The desired functionality would be to keep the user logged in, but to disregard that login when the user is on the archive page and treat the user as an unauthenticated user.

I've removed all login/user controls from a custom skin file, but DNN still serves the uncached page.

Is there a solution to this? Thanks in advance to any and all ideas/solutions.

P.S. I considered going the cookie way, but there seems to be no way to give access to all pages except those with path /science/..., etc. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is not supported. Mainly because even if the content supported it the page has other items. Login link, etc that cannot be cached for authenticated users.

Comment: Just to clarify, @mitchel-sellers, removing login link control and other similar things from the skin file does not stop DNN from treating the user as authenticated?

Comment: That is correct, authenticated is authenticated as far as it is concerned.  It will NOT output cache it.